# Are svn revision numbers chronological?

Tags: svn

In the process of converting a svn repo with several (chaotic) branches to git and not being really familiar with svn I need some help.  Going through the logs in a copy checked out from svn I find this:

*branch1:*

```
r1985 | (no author) | 2007-07-25 15:17:52 +0200 (Wed, 25 Jul 2007) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /Project/HEAD/project2001b (from /project2001b:1984)
   D /project2001b

r4 | (no author) | 2007-07-23 14:48:58 +0200 (Mon, 23 Jul 2007) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /project2001b
```

*branch2:*

```
r1989 | (no author) | 2007-07-25 15:22:59 +0200 (Wed, 25 Jul 2007) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /Project/branches/Project_2001 (from /Project_2001:1988)
   D /Project_2001

r178 | (no author) | 2001-01-15 12:16:41 +0100 (Mon, 15 Jan 2001) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /Project_2001
```

Why is svn revision **r4** from a later date than revision **r178**? My understanding of svn wouldn't allow this. What am I missing?  Is the svn repo broken somehow?  I also can't find a revision r2.  Can svn revisions disappear from the logs?  Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For poorly administered SVN-repository you can't really trust any metadata in it

Unversioned revision-properties

```
svn pl --revprop -r ...
Unversioned properties on revision 7:
  svn:author
  svn:date
  svn:log
```

can be changed at any time from client-side with `svn propset`

With administrative access to repository (really - physical access to FS) dumping|editing dump|loading dumps back can produce even more tricks (f.e partial dumps may produce disappearing of range of revisions, editing dumps - any exotic effects as reordering)

Sample for one revision in dump

```
Revision-number: 5
Prop-content-length: 146
Content-length: 146

K 10
svn:author
V 6
abream
K 8
svn:date
V 27
2012-10-17T15:45:47.444624Z
K 7
svn:log
V 45
Remove externals definition from root of repo
PROPS-END
```

in this (text) representation of revision in dump anybody can (theoretically) change carefully some data and after loading such faked-dump get in repository this new information without any traces of old, presumably correct (and, f.e revision 555 will appear before 6)

Comment: Thanks. Managed to sift through this mess with `svn log -r 1:HEAD -v`